# Why would someone keep sending money to my Paypal account without my consent?

Tags: paypal

I don't know why someone keeps sending money to my Paypal account, repeatedly at a certain interval. What would be the benefit from doing this?

What would be the security scenario in maliciously using my Paypal account?

What should I do to stop it?

Comment: Spend it quickly.

Comment: how much are they sending each time?

Answer (score 14):

It would be wise to contact Paypal security immediately. This may just be a mistake but it could also be part of a scam to be able to "freeze" funds or access your account legally to recover transferred funds plus additional funds.

I would also recommend to immediately change your e-mail and Paypal password. Someone may be using your accounts to launder money and it's possible they may have more access to your on-line accounts than you think.

Comment: if its coming from one entity it could also be a way to try and desensitise the account to the person, how much they are sending each time would certainly confirm the potential issues, small amounts would likely be a desensitisation and large amounts possibly laundering...

Answer (score 3):

One common scam is to send people money "accidently" then ask for it "back". The "accidental" transcation turns out to be fraudulant and gets reversed leaving it's recipiant out of pocket if they complied with the request for a refund.